# How do you translate the following sentence?

Tags: traducción

"There have been rumours for a long time but it looks official now"

The correct translation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se]. What did you research on this? Note it is discouraged to ask for translations without any attempts done by yourself.

Comment: Not sure if this is OT. A possible translation is había rumores desde hace tiempo, pero ahora parece ser oficial. Depending on the degree of formality the wording may change a little. Depending on the context, verb tenses in había and hace might change too.

Comment: *Ha habido rumores durante un largo tiempo pero **luce** oficial ahora*. You can replace the bolded word with a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the grade of (Spanish) neutrality you want to achieve, but my take would be:

"Han corrido rumores desde hace un tiempo, pero parece que ya es oficial".